# JASidePanels, touch not recognized in right panel

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

On iPad landscape, I have a right panel that occupies almost all the width of the screen.

I have configured the panel this way

```
[[self viewController] setShouldResizeRightPanel:YES];
[[self viewController] setRightGapPercentage:0.93f];
[[self viewController] setAllowRightOverpan:YES];
```

The problem is that I can't touch the left part of the right panel (~25% of the view does not responds to touches). If I set `shouldResizeRightPanel` to `NO` then it takes the 80% percent of the available width (that is the default value for rightGapPercentage) and the touch works properly, but the panel does not occupies the entire available width.

Is this a bug or did I missed something I have to configure to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this but I don't know if this is the correct way.

In the method,

```
- (void)_animateCenterPanel:(BOOL)shouldBounce completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

comment the conditional `if (self.style == JASidePanelMultipleActive)` of the animations block to allow the correct layout of the side containers `[self _layoutSideContainers:NO duration:0.0f];` in every style.

For now it is working properly.

EDIT

Well, I've continued investigating and I end in `_layoutSidePanels`. There is a conditional `if (self.shouldResizeRightPanel) {` and this is the old code:

```
frame.origin.x = self.rightPanelContainer.bounds.size.width - self.rightVisibleWidth;
frame.size.width = self.rightVisibleWidth;
```

And this is my code. With this the panel is correctly lay out and all of it is tapable. The prior solution was wrong.

```
[self.rightPanelContainer setWidth:self.rightVisibleWidth];
[self.rightPanelContainer setOriginX:self.rightVisibleWidth * (1.0f - self.rightGapPercentage)];
frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
frame.size.width = self.rightVisibleWidth;
```

I think there is something more in the guts of the code.